Файлы в PyCharm подсвечиваются цветом Hijacked (Угнанный). Файлы не запускаются
Ранее при запуске PyCharm столкнулась с ошибкой "Cannot connect to already running IDE instance. Exception: Process 7,416 is still running". По совету из форумов удалила файлы lock на скриншоте 1.

Не сработало, восстановила их и перезагрузила ноутбук. После перезагрузки открыла PyCharm, запустила код и все файлы в папке pythonProject начали подсвечиваться оранжевым цветом

При их запуске вылезает окно как на скриншоте.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно решить эту проблему.
